# Apache and mono can't find the default controller and show the homepage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, mono, ubuntu-18.04, apache2.4

I am going to host an asp.net MVC 5 website (.net framework) on ubuntu server.
The asp.net MVC 5 project that I am using is an asp.net MVC template from MonoDevelop. (Very simple project)
I have used apache2 and installed mono based on this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@shrimpy/configure-apache2-mod-mono-to-run-asp-net-mvc5-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-314a700522b9?

but it doesn't work and it only shows the directories and files when I go to 127.0.0.1:80
Here is the page I face on the browser:

https://ibb.co/nLjYjZG

Here is my webapp.conf (which is /etc/apache2/site-available/webapp.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 ServerName kudutry.scm.cloudapp.net
 MonoAutoApplication disabled
 AddHandler mono .aspx ascx .asax .ashx .config .cs .asmx .axd
 MonoApplications “/:/home/azureuser/webapp”
 MonoServerPath kudutry.scm.cloudapp.net /usr/bin/mod-mono-server4



 DocumentRoot /home/azureuser/webapp
 <Directory />
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 </Directory>

 <Directory “/home/azureuser/webapp”>

 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
 SetHandler mono
 DirectoryIndex index.html 
 </Directory>

 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

 <Directory “/usr/lib/cgi-bin”>
 AllowOverride None
 Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/kudu-error.log
 # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
 # alert, emerg.
 LogLevel warn
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/kudu-access.log combined

 </VirtualHost>

Alias /scm “/home/azureuser/webapp”
 # MonoServerPath can be changed to specify which version of ASP.NET is hosted
 # mod-mono-server1 = ASP.NET 1.1 / mod-mono-server2 = ASP.NET 2.0
 # For SUSE Linux Enterprise Mono Extension, uncomment the line below:
 # MonoServerPath scm “/opt/novell/mono/bin/mod-mono-server2”
 # For Mono on openSUSE, uncomment the line below instead:
 MonoServerPath scm “/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4”
 # To obtain line numbers in stack traces you need to do two things: 
 # 1) Enable Debug code generation in your page by using the Debug=”true” 
 # page directive, or by setting <compilation debug=”true” /> in the 
 # application’s Web.config
 # 2) Uncomment the MonoDebug true directive below to enable mod_mono debugging
 MonoDebug scm true

 # The MONO_IOMAP environment variable can be configured to provide platform abstraction
 # for file access in Linux. Valid values for MONO_IOMAP are:
 # case
 # drive
 # all
 # Uncomment the line below to alter file access behavior for the configured application
 MonoSetEnv scm MONO_IOMAP=all
 #
 # Additional environtment variables can be set for this server instance using 
 # the MonoSetEnv directive. MonoSetEnv takes a string of ‘name=value’ pairs 
 # separated by semicolons. For instance, to enable platform abstraction *and* 
 # use Mono’s old regular expression interpreter (which is slower, but has a
 # shorter setup time), uncomment the line below instead:
 # MonoSetEnv scm MONO_IOMAP=all;MONO_OLD_RX=1
MonoApplications scm “/scm:/home/azureuser/webapp”
 <Location “/scm”>
 Allow from all
 Order allow,deny
 MonoSetServerAlias scm
 SetHandler mono
 SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
 SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI “\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$” no-gzip dont-vary
 </Location>
 <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
 </IfModule>
```

Here is my mod_mono.conf (which is /etc/apache2/mod_mono.conf):

```
# mod_mono.conf

# Use 'include mod_mono.conf' from other configuration file
# to load mod_mono module.

<IfModule !mod_mono.c>
    LoadModule mono_module /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_mono.so
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Powered-By "Mono"
</IfModule>

AddType application/x-asp-net .aspx
AddType application/x-asp-net .asmx
AddType application/x-asp-net .ashx
AddType application/x-asp-net .asax
AddType application/x-asp-net .ascx
AddType application/x-asp-net .soap
AddType application/x-asp-net .rem
AddType application/x-asp-net .axd
AddType application/x-asp-net .cs
AddType application/x-asp-net .vb
AddType application/x-asp-net .master
AddType application/x-asp-net .sitemap
AddType application/x-asp-net .resources
AddType application/x-asp-net .skin
AddType application/x-asp-net .browser
AddType application/x-asp-net .webinfo
AddType application/x-asp-net .resx
AddType application/x-asp-net .licx
AddType application/x-asp-net .csproj
AddType application/x-asp-net .vbproj
AddType application/x-asp-net .config
AddType application/x-asp-net .Config
AddType application/x-asp-net .dll

DirectoryIndex index.aspx
DirectoryIndex Default.aspx
DirectoryIndex default.aspx
#DirectoryIndex Global.asax

# NOTE: I'm not sure why this is needed when the app paths are also defined in the MonoApplications section
Alias /MyApplicationName "/Library/WebServer/Documents/path-to-web-app-directory"

# MonoServerPath can be changed to specify which version of ASP.NET is hosted
# mod-mono-server1 = ASP.NET 1.1 / mod-mono-server2 = ASP.NET 2.0
MonoServerPath MyApplicationName "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"

# To obtain line numbers in stack traces you need to do two things: 
# 1) Enable Debug code generation in your page by using the Debug="true" 
#    page directive, or by setting <compilation debug="true" /> in the 
#    application's Web.config
# 2) Uncomment the MonoDebug true directive below to enable mod_mono debugging
MonoDebug MyApplicationName true

# The MONO_IOMAP environment variable can be configured to provide platform abstraction
# for file access in Linux.  Valid values for MONO_IOMAP are:
#    case
#    drive
#    all
# Uncomment the line below to alter file access behavior for the configured application
MonoSetEnv MyApplicationName MONO_IOMAP=all




# Additional environtment variables can be set for this server instance using 
# the MonoSetEnv directive.  MonoSetEnv takes a string of 'name=value' pairs 
# separated by semicolons.  For instance, to enable platform abstraction *and* 
# use Mono's old regular expression interpreter (which is slower, but has a
# shorter setup time), uncomment the line below instead:
# MonoSetEnv MyApplicationName MONO_IOMAP=all;MONO_OLD_RX=1

MonoApplications MyApplicationName "/MyApplicationName:/Library/WebServer/Documents/path-to-web-app-directory"
<Location "/MyApplicationName">
Allow from all
Order allow,deny
MonoSetServerAlias MyApplicationName
SetHandler mono
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
</Location>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
</IfModule>
```

Here is my apache2.conf (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf)

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
#

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 600

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/azureuser/webapp>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

#Novataris added

Include /etc/apache2/mod_mono.conf
```

Comment: I also have to mention that I have copied the folder that contains global.asax into the website directory. [/home/azureuser/webapp]

Comment: If it is really simple, please switch to ASP.NET Core. The old ASP.NET on Mono is not a feasible option any more.

Comment: @Lexi Li: We have to use Mono rather than core. So I appreciate if you help with mono if you know what the problem is.

Comment: You are stepping into a field that most people exited, so enjoy your adventure.

Comment: @ArashMAS: why do you have to?

Comment: @knocte: Due to the time limit we wanted to migrate our solution to Mono and run it on a Linux server. Because we thought it will take less time than migrating to the .net core. we do not need it anymore but personally, I am very interested to find the problem and be able to run an MVC 5 sample project on mono with apache. So I will appreciate if you can help.

Comment: I guarantee you that running it in .NETCore will take you less time than mono